# timed_join(0) : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const int'

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I tried to check if a thread is running with use of `timed_join(0)`. But unlike others, I get this error:

> 1>c:...\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp(538): error **C2679**: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

It looks like the `timed_join()` is not correctly defined to use `int`. But how come I am the only one who got this error? (try to search the title, I got 3 total results at google)

Comment: Please provide a SSCCE http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`timed_join()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.timed_join) is deprecated in recent versions of boost, the [documentation overview](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/build.html) describes the rationale for this in greater detail. It looks like this interface will be removed after boost 1.56. In any case, the correct usage of `timed_join()` is to supply a `posix_time` value, such as

```
thread.timed_join(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(0))
```